# Adding hero images to blog posts

Tags: plugins, images, admin

I'm having some trouble finding the solution for my problem stated in the title. To describe it more clearly, then I would like to add some kind of functionality to the wordpress post section in the admin panel, where my boss or other co-workers can add both a thumbnail image for the listing of blog posts, but also a unique header image for that given post, when you click to the full post it should show the added header image for that given post. Is that possible and how? :)

Cheers!

Comment: For single post you can us the built-in [post thumbnails](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails). For the listing of blog posts, do you mean the categories archives, blog index, tags archives, ....?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the [Advanced Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) plugin for that. Beside that, ACF provides you more field types you can use. And instead of showing the featured image in single.php, you can echo the one uploaded in your additional field.

Comment: That is exactly what I need! Do you know any resources, that can guide me in how to call the custom field in the single.php file? Just startet with wordpress dev and php.

Many thx.

Comment: @MikkelMadsen http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources